# Javascript ,how to combine two variables into a third

Tags: javascript, printing

I'm working on a project to look at alternative ways to deploy printers to users from an html page residing on an internal SharePoint site.

I've found some code someone had posted that seems to work well, but I was looking to see if I could change it a little to suit our needs a little better, allowing for a cleaner way to create hundreds of new printer installation links.

This works for us.

```js
var WshNetwork = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Network"); 
var PrinterPath = "\\\\printserver-a\\printer-a"; 
WshNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection(PrinterPath); //Does the adding of the printer
WshNetwork.SetDefaultPrinter(PrinterPath); //Sets printer as system default
```

Rather than have to modify the PrinterPath variable, what I'd like to define ahead of time is a PrintServer variable as well as a Printer variable, then combine those two variables into a 3rd, listed in the printer path.

I've tried some examples I've seen, and have spoken to a colleague who has a better understanding of JavaScript, but could not find anything that works for me.
I was thinking something like this.

```js
var PrintServer = "printserver-a";
var Printer = "printer-a";
var WshNetwork = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Network"); 
var PrinterPath = "\\\\PrintServer\\Printer"; 
WshNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection(PrinterPath); //Does the adding of the printer
WshNetwork.SetDefaultPrinter(PrinterPath); //Sets printer as system default
```

But this is not working for me, and am looking to see what it is I'm missing. I have no understanding of JavaScript whatsoever, but have found this to be one of the best solutions for us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want to concatenate a few strings together. Here's one way to do that in JavaScript:

```
var PrintServer = 'printserver-a';
var Printer = 'printer-a';
var PrinterPath = '\\\\' + PrintServer + '\\' + Printer;
```

In modern JavaScript (aka ES6) you can use template literals to accomplish what you want, like so:

```
var PrintServer = 'printserver-a';
var Printer = 'printer-a';
var PrinterPath = `\\\\${Printer}\\${Printer}`;
```

Note that PrinterPath must use backticks instead of single quotes.

Now here's are an unsolicited tip, since you're just starting to learn JavaScript: The general convention in JS is to use variable names that are not capitalized (the exception to this would be for "class" functions).

Comment: Thank you, string concatenation worked for me. Thanks you for your input regarding capitalization.  Changing the double quote to single ticks is what was wrong in my first attempt at concatenation yesterday. Additionally, the template literals would not work since our requirement is IE.

Answer (score 1):

A [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) would be effective here:

```
var PrinterPath = `\\\\${PrintServer}\\${Printer}`;
```

Alternatively, string concatenation:

```
var PrinterPath = "\\\\" + PrintServer + "\\" + Printer;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try template literals

```
var PrinterPath = `\\\\${PrintServer}\\${Printer}`;
```

This will evaluate to have your variables here as strings
You can read up on this [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: You're not using a template literal.  You forgot to use backticks (``) instead of the usual quotation marks ("").

Answer (score 0):

You can use basic [string concatenation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Addition_()), or possibly [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).  The difference is that template literals are new to JavaScript and aren't supported on Internet Explorer at all, just modern browsers.  You can check the [compatibility table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Browser_compatibility). 
 The change you'd have to make would just be the following line.  Below I've listed the two solutions.

With string concatenation:

```
var PrinterPath = "\\\\" + PrintServer + "\\" + Printer;
```

With template literals:

```
var PrinterPath = `\\\\${PrintServer}\\${Printer}`;
```